# How to modify this query in order to include optional filtration?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-charts

I have an ASP.NET chart control that will show the estimated time vs time spent by each student on each class activity. I would like to have 
a dropdownlist control to filter the chart by the activity status; All, Open, Closed.
I already populated the chart control and dropdownlist control with the data from the database. However, I am struggling now with 
modifying my query in order to filter the chart based on the selection in the dropdownlist.

The chart should display all the activities at the beginning (by default). Then, when the user selects a status from the dropdownlist, then
the chart will be filtered based on the selection

**So how can I modify my query to include this optional filtration?**

DB schema:

```
Task Table: TaskId, Title, EstimatedTime, StatusId
Entry Table: EntryId, TaskId
EntryDetails Table: EntryDetailsId, EntryId, Hours
Status Table: StatusId, Name
```

Here's my query:

```
SELECT     tbl_Task.Title AS [Task Title], tbl_Task.EstimatedTime AS [Estimated Time], SUM(tbl_EntryDetails.Hours) AS [Time Spent]
FROM         tbl_EntryDetails INNER JOIN
                      tbl_Entry ON tbl_EntryDetails.EntryId = tbl_Entry.EntryId RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                      tbl_Task ON tbl_Entry.TaskId = tbl_Task.TaskId
GROUP BY tbl_Task.Title, tbl_Task.EstimatedTime
```

Comment: Are you just asking how to construct a where clause?

Comment: Add where tbl_Task.StatusId == selected item value from the dropdown list.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I think if I put this where condition, then no data will be retrieved if the user selects nothing from the dropdownlist. The chart should display all the data at the beginning and it will be filtered in case there is a selection of status.

Comment: You need to use Coalesce function to achieve that

Comment: Dear @sqlhdv could you please help me with my query?

Comment: declare a variable for the value of the dropdown list (say, @DropdownStatus). Then make your where clause "WHERE (@DropdownStatus = 'All' or tbl_task.StatusID = @DropdownStatus)"